# Inheriting List to Sortable List-protected members out of scope

Tags: c++

I am developing a list in which I have used some protected variables `count`, `entry[maxlist]` etc.

**List.h**

```
class List
    {
    public:
    //etc etc

    protected:
    int count;
    int entry[maxlist];
    };
```

**Sortable_list.h**

```
typedef Key Record;
class Sortable_list:public List<Record>
{
void selection_sort()
    {
        for(int position=count-1;position>0;i--) // Count is not declared in the scope
        {
        int max=max_key(0, position);
        swap(max, position);
        }
    }
};
```

Is something wrong with inheriting the List to Sortable List? Why is it showing count out of scope?

Comment: Are you inheriting the right List? Your List.h is not a template class, but your inheriting from List<Record>...

Comment: It is actually a template. I just wrote by hand in the above. Here's the full code of List.h : pastebin.com/3xTADqvN Is something wrong in this?

Comment: I tested your code and except some problems due to `using namespace std` and the use of `i` instead of `position` in your `for` loop, your code compiles. Are you sure you include `List.h` in `Sortable_list.h`?

Comment: Yes, I am including `List.h` in `Sortable_list.h`. Here's the full code of `Sortable_list.h` too. http://pastebin.com/k1ARsyCR

Answer (score 1):

**#Edit:** After seeing your whole code it becomes clearer. You're having ambiguities because of your includes, it will compile with msvc, because it handles such cases silently, but for g++ you should explicitly state that `count` is from this class, by doing `this->count`. You also had problems because of `std::range_error`, which could be avoided by removing `using namespace std` or replacing `range_error` with `::range_error` which will indicate that you want the global scope. Another problem with your code is that, you were using an undefined variable `i` in your `Sortable_list`. The fixed code that compiles with g++ and msvc: http://codepad.org/7V70rNqf

I don't want to sound rude, but I strongly suggest you read a book on C++, your current code is very anti-idiomatic, and could be made generic with a smaller amount of code.

Comment: It is actually a template. I just wrote by hand in the above. Here's the full code of List.h : pastebin.com/3xTADqvN Is something wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) function template from `<algorithm>` header? All you need to write just one small `Compare` function.

Answer (score 0):

Look like your `List` is not a template class, so `List< Typename >` doesn't exist ..
Also, you can use `std::set<T>` as a template class for sorted container => http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html

Comment: It is actually a template. I just wrote by hand in the above. Here's the full code of List.h : http://pastebin.com/3xTADqvN Is something wrong in this?